# trying to call a method within a method

Tags: java, oop, methods, compiler-errors

Trying to call a method within a method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sq,cu=0;

    //user input 1
    sq=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "Enter value to be squared"));
    //user input 2
    cu=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "Enter value to be cubed"));
    //results
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqd(sq));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cbd(cu));


}
public static String sqd(int sq){
    int sqd=sq*sq;
    //sq computation
    return sq+" squared is "+sqd;
}
public static String cbd(int cu,int sqd){
    int cbd;
    cbd=sqd*cu;
    //cu computation
    return cu+" cubed is "+cbd;
}    }
```

calling sqd value in cbd, but

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cbd(cu));
```

prevents me from doing so, it always gives me an error when I run it.

Comment: *"gives me an error"* - what error?

Comment: You get an error because `cbd` takes two parameters while you pass only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `cbd(int cu, int sqd)` method needs **2** input parameters , you are calling it with only **one** parameter `cbd(cu)`

two choices :

1 - rewrite your `cbd` method with 1 parameter then you can call it using `cbd(cu);`

```
public static String cbd(int cu){
    return cu + " cubed is " + (cu*cu*cu);
}
```

2 - write it's second parameter while you are using it :

```
 cbd(cu,cu*cu);
```

Comment: how will i write the second parameter?

Comment: `cbd( cu , cu*cu )`

Comment: thank you! it's fixed now. but i'm curious, why does it work?

Comment: which one ? first choice or second choice?

Comment: the second choice. why does(cu,cu*cu) work? how does it work?

Comment: becuase you need to pass two parameters , first one is cu , but you need to have second parameter, because  you have implemented `cbd=sqd*cu;` so your `sqd` must be a value that squared the `cu` , sqd is the `second` parameter , so i used `cu*cu` as second parameter

Comment: thank you for the explanation :D

Comment: yw , good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `cbd` method, as it's currently defined, takes two arguments - `cu` and `sqd`. If you want to keep the way your `main` calls it, you need to rewrite it with just one argument:

```
public static String cbd(int cu){
    int cbd = cu * cu * cu;
    return cu + " cubed is " + cbd;
}
```